# Does cnosdb-cli support specify system-proxy

Tags: cnosdb

Now on windows and linux (not mac), the cnosdb-cli may detect and use system-proxy automatically, I want to add a switch to determine whether the cnosdb-cli requests cnosdb through my proxy.
Such as a parameter --proxy <proxy_url>，if user do not give that argument, then cnosdb-cli request the cnosdb directly.

Comment: cnosdb is too niche and many people don’t understand it.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is actually very important in some cases where an agency must be used